# How should i factory reset SD card / USB drive st MacOS can automatically mount it?

Tags: linux, mac, partitioning, mount, sd-card

After taking SD card from my IP camera (some version of linux), the card could not be mounted in MacOS anymore. In Mac DiskUtils, the card was said to have 0 free space and 100% used even after formatting to FAT32 using Mac DiskUtils.

On the other hand, the card could be mounted in linux. I wiped the filesystem, `dd` zeros to the disk, created a new partition (W95 FAT32), and `mkfs.vfat`. It worked just fine in linux. But when put it back in Mac, it still could not be mounted automatically. It can only be mounted using command line in Mac Terminal.

Is there a way to “factory reset” a USB drive or SD card such that it’s like new to Mac or Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Try the official formatter from the SD Card Association - https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/

If that can't do it, there's something wrong with the card.